# Powershell insert into MS Access with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, powershell, ms-access

Trying to insert values into MS Access DB based on values entered into a powershell form with a WHERE clause. I'm receiving a simple error but struggling to resolve ("Missing Semicolon (;) at end of SQL Statement")

Here is my base code;

```
$query = "INSERT INTO SignIns ([DateTimeOUT], [SignedOut]) VALUES ('$($info.F1)','$($info.F2)') FROM $Info WHERE SignIns.Surname = '$($Info.F3)'" 
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $query
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.Close()
```

I've amended to add a semicolon in all places I thought could resolve, but no luck, still returns the same error (Missing Semi Colon at end of SQL statement);

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO SignIns ([DateTimeOUT], [SignedOut]) VALUES ('$($info.F1)','$($info.F2)') FROM $Info WHERE SignIns.Surname = '$($Info.F3);';"; 
    $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = $query;
    $result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    $conn.Close()
```

(for reference, I've added a semi-colon at the end of my WHERE clause, at the end of the $Query variable and tried to append onto the end of $query when executing in the $cmd.commandtext variable, and also on the end of the $result variable.

I expect the statement to execute as normal and update with the given values. Testing within Access DB itself is difficult as I am unable to reference my PS form from within the DB. Any help greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Ameding query to UPDATE now lets me 'insert' values with WHERE statement following a simple logic.

```
$conn.Open()
$query = "UPDATE SignIns SET DateTimeOUT = '$($info.F1)' WHERE SignIns.Surname = '$($Info.F3)'";
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $query;
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

$query = "UPDATE SignIns SET SignedOut = '$($info.F2)' WHERE SignIns.Surname = '$($Info.F3)'";
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $query;
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
$conn.Close()
```

It is not a method I'm normally use to when inputting new values into a table, but same result so.. I don't think there's any implications. It probably takes the update as 'Update from NULL to VALUE' as opposed to INSERT FROM source to DESINTATION (where)

Comment: What do you get if you run `$info.GetType()` and `$info.Count` in PowerShell? You should certainly be able to insert values for multiple columns. It seems however that you can't insert multiple rows in one go (as discussed in the question you've linked to). The FROM-bit (`FROM $Info`) seems a little peculiar as well.

Comment: Yeah I thought that, I thought the syntax followed a Destination / Source format so thought I had to specify my update value FROM source just for syntax purposes.. I have it working now anyhow. I changed my query to UPDATE and that works a treat, will post answer & close now. Thanks for your input, will check on the $Info.GetType() / $Info.Count as the error has puzzled me (I can Insert no problem if I don't use the WHERE clause.. soon as I added that in, errors started)